# Is there a way to make sure that I only see Chromecast devices where my App will run?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

If I have two Chromecast devices and only one of them is whitelisted, it would be great to only seem the one I can use listed.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In our Sample App for using MediaRouter, CastSampleActivity.java had the line in it's onCreate  method that looked like:

```
mMediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteHelper
                .buildMediaRouteSelector(MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST);
```

We've changed that to:

```
 mMediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteHelper
        .buildMediaRouteSelector(MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST,
                getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) /* APPID */, null);
```

Or

```
builder.addControlCategory(MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_PREFIX_CAST_APP_NAME + AppID);
```

With this your apps will only see devices where your app can run, a much better solution for the user.

Comment: It's interesting that the Android library works this way. In the Chrome Cast API you have to specify the application type ID in order to receive messages about available receivers: api.addReceiverListener(appId, callback)